# Map over hashes that themselves are values in a hash?

Tags: ruby

Suppose I want to map over the hashes that are themselves the values contained in a hash:

```rb
h = {:tier_0=>{:s=>0, :fee=>20}, :tier_1=>{:s=>1, :fee=>18}}
```

(that is, to map over `{:s=>0, :fee=>20}`, `{:s=>1, :fee=>18}` etc

How can I do that?

I got this but it's a nested `.map{}`, I'm sure there's a better way this this?

```rb
h.map{ |k, v| v.map{ |s, f| puts f}}
```

Answer (score 4):

If there are only two levels, then

Input

```
h = {:tier_0=>{:s=>0, :fee=>20}, :tier_1=>{:s=>1, :fee=>18}}
```

Code

```
p h.values.map{|x|x.values}
```

Output

```
[[0, 20], [1, 18]]
```

Comment: ...or `h.values.flat_map(&:values) #=> [0, 20, 1, 18]`.